# Unable to get the number of alphabets/digits/special characters in a given string

Tags: c#

String: This is  a string with with alphabets digits 123 special characters @#!

here is my program:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string to calculate alphabets,digits and special characters");
        string userstr = Console.ReadLine();

        int alphabet, splch, digits;
        alphabet = splch = digits = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < userstr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (userstr[i] >= 'a' || userstr[i] <= 'z')
            {
                alphabet++;
            }
            else if (userstr[i] >= 0 || userstr[i] <= 9)
            {
                digits++;
            }

            else { splch++; }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("No of Alphabets {0},digits {1}, special characters {2} in given string are", alphabet, digits, splch);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you facing issue in this code? what issue?

Comment: Replace || with &&. And you should handle capital letters. You’d Better use standard functions.

Answer (score 2):

You had heaps of mistakes,

1. you need `&&` instead of `||`
2. you need to account for capitals
3. you were comparing your numbers wrong and not using the char for `0` and `9`

Code (i took the liberty of converting it a `foreach`)

```
foreach (var c in userstr)
{
   if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      alphabet++;
   else if (c >= '0'&& c <= '9')
      digits++;
   else
      splch++;     
}
```

or

```
foreach (var c in input)
{
   if (char.IsLetter(c))
      alphabet++;
   else if (char.IsDigit(c))
      digits++;
   else
      splch++; 
}
```